# Unable to get the element using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use selenium to automatically click on the "Easy Apply" option after I get the search results for a particular job. This is the code I tried but unable to find any element:

```
apply_list = []
easy_apply = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "job-card-container__apply-method job-card-container__footer-item inline-flex align-items-center")
for easy in easy_apply:
    apply_list.append(easy.text)

 print(apply_list)
```

Comment: Add the `HTML` of the element please

Comment: An [Explicit wait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/) may helps

Comment: ```<ul class="job-card-list__footer-wrapper job-card-container__footer-wrapper flex-shrink-zero display-flex t-sans t-12 t-black--light t-normal t-roman">
            <li class="job-card-container__footer-item inline-flex align-items-center">
              <!---->Promoted<!---->
            </li>
                      <li class="job-card-container__apply-method job-card-container__footer-item inline-flex align-items-center">                                                     ```

Answer (score 1):

`By.CLASS_NAME()` always accepts `single` class name, It doesn't support multiple class names. Instead you should use `By.CSS_SELECTOR()`

```
apply_list = []
easy_apply = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".job-card-container__apply-method.job-card-container__footer-item.inline-flex.align-items-center")
for easy in easy_apply:
    apply_list.append(easy.text)

 print(apply_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try if the below line of code manages to locate element:

```
easy_apply = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//li[contains(@class,'job-card-container__apply-method job-card-container__footer-item inline-flex align-items-center')]")
```

Comment: I tried that but it does not select the exact option "Easy Apply", so that I can apply the resume. Please note that I have changed apply_list.append(easy.text) to apply_list.append(easy) and then used apply_list.click().

Answer (score 0):

Finally. This worked for me

```
easy_apply = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.jobs-s-apply button')
easy_apply.click()
```